# JSON and whitespaces in identifiers

Tags: javascript, json

Question: The JavaScript code below:
records is JSON serialized data.
I can access it right away from JavaScript by using for example 
    alert(records.data[0].Phone);

The problem now is that some bright spark used a whitespace in FirstName and LastName, which means I would have to access it like
alert(records.data[0].Last Name);
 Which of course is not possible. 
Is there any way to access it with the whitespace, like an escape sequence?
I already tried omitting the whitespace, or replacing it with underscore.
The problem is I get the record, and I have no control over the source.

```
    var records = {
"data" : [
    {
        "First Name" : "John",
        "Last Name" : "Doe",
        "Email" : "nobody@example.com",
        "Phone" : "(917) 41-6598",
    },
    {
        "First Name" : "Thomas",
        "Last Name" : "Brown",
        "Email" : "somebody@example.com",
        "Phone" : "(917) 41-2892",
    },
    {
        "First Name" : "Albert",
        "Last Name" : "Hansen",
        "Email" : "someone@example.com",
        "Phone" : "(917) 41-3769",
    }
]};



alert(records.data[0].Email);
alert(records.data[0].Phone);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 alert(records.data[0]["Last Name"]);
```

`data["x"]` is equivalent to `data.x`